# $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}(\tan^{9}x+5\tan ^{7}x+5\tan^{5}x+\tan^{3}x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}(\tan^{9}x+5\tan ^{7}x+5\tan^{5}x+\tan^{3}x)dx$$

I found that: $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}(\tan^{n+2}x+\tan^{n}x)dx=\frac{1}{n+1},\,n>0$

I tried to combine the terms: the first one with the last one then to factor, didn't get too far. Also, I tried to combine the first one with the second one then to factor but I get stuck.

Some ideas?

Comment: Use what you found and group them like this: $\tan^9x+\tan^7x+4(\tan^7x+\tan^5x)+\tan^5x+\tan^3x$

Comment: What are $t$ and $g$?

Comment: tangent function

Comment: @ViktorGlombik different notation for tangent

Answer (score 3):

Set $\tan x=t$

$$t^9+t^3+5t^5(1+t^2)$$

$$=t^3((t^2)^3+1^3)+5t^5(1+t^2)$$

$$=\underbrace{(1+t^2)}t^3(1-t^2+t^4)+5t^5\underbrace{(1+t^2)}$$